# Load bitmap object data into array of byte values

Tags: image, f#

I'm building this as part of a larger class to rapidly search for smaller images inside larger images. This is my first serious F# project so comments especially concerning style and organization are appreciated.

```
module imagesearch = 
    type BitmapSearchClass() = 
        // Largely inspired by this article
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspx
        static member loadBitmapIntoArray (pBitmap:Bitmap) =
            let tBitmapRectangle = Rectangle(0, 0, pBitmap.Width, pBitmap.Height)

            let tLockMode = ImageLockMode.ReadOnly
            let tImageFormat = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb

            let tBitmapData = pBitmap.LockBits(tBitmapRectangle, tLockMode, tImageFormat) 
            let tIntPtr = tBitmapData.Scan0

            let tImageByteLength = Math.Abs(tBitmapData.Stride) * pBitmap.Height

            // Zerocreate creates the "empty" array
            let tImageRGBValues : byte array = Array.zeroCreate tImageByteLength

            do Marshal.Copy(tImageRGBValues, 0, tIntPtr, tImageByteLength)

            do pBitmap.UnlockBits(tBitmapData)

            tImageRGBValues, pBitmap.Width, pBitmap.Height
```

**Current state of the module is below**

```
module ImageSearch = 
    type BitmapSearch() = 
        // Largely inspired by this article
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspx
        static member LoadBitmapIntoArray (pBitmap:Bitmap) =
            let tBitmapData = pBitmap.LockBits( Rectangle(Point.Empty, pBitmap.Size), 
                                                ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, 
                                                PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb )  

            let tImageArrayLength = Math.Abs(tBitmapData.Stride) * pBitmap.Height
            let tImageDataArray = Array.zeroCreate<byte> tImageArrayLength

            Marshal.Copy(tImageDataArray, 0, tBitmapData.Scan0, tImageArrayLength)
            pBitmap.UnlockBits(tBitmapData)

            tImageDataArray, pBitmap.Width, pBitmap.Height
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module imagesearch =
```

All types should use `PascalCase`, this includes modules. So the correct name would be `ImageSearch`.

---

```
type BitmapSearchClass() =
```

That's a weird name, names of classes shouldn't end with `Class`. And why is it a class in the first place? If it contains only `static` members, it should probably be a `module`.

---

```
static member loadBitmapIntoArray (pBitmap:Bitmap) =
```

Public methods should also use PascalCase (`LoadBitmapIntoArray`).

---

```
pBitmap:Bitmap
let tBitmapRectangle = …
```

Prefixing each parameter with `p` and each local variable with `t` seems like a weird kind of [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). Please don't do that, it doesn't serve any purpose.

---

```
Rectangle(0, 0, pBitmap.Width, pBitmap.Height)
```

A shorter way to write this would be:

```
Rectangle(Point.Empty, pBitmap.Size)
```

---

```
let tLockMode = ImageLockMode.ReadOnly
let tImageFormat = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb

let tBitmapData = pBitmap.LockBits(tBitmapRectangle, tLockMode, tImageFormat)
```

Why are these variables? Since you never use them again, and since naming them doesn't add any useful information, you can just write them directly in the function call:

```
let tBitmapData = pBitmap.LockBits(tBitmapRectangle, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
```

---

```
let tImageRGBValues : byte array = Array.zeroCreate tImageByteLength
```

Another way to specify the type is to add type parameter to `zeroCreate`:

```
let tImageRGBValues = Array.zeroCreate<byte> tImageByteLength
```

---

```
do Marshal.Copy(tImageRGBValues, 0, tIntPtr, tImageByteLength)

do pBitmap.UnlockBits(tBitmapData)
```

You don't need to write `do` here. (Actually, [I was surprised you *can* write `do` here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24779957/41071).)

Comment: Prefixing each parameter with p and each local variable with t seems like a weird kind of Hungarian notation. Please don't do that, it doesn't serve any purpose. <- Just to address this, I'm a huge fan of using intellisense and autocomplete to speed up my development, and I find prefixing some values (p for parameters, t for local scoped, and a few others) with a single letter tends to make using the intellisense easier. It's a habit from C#. All the rest of what you said looks great though, thanks for the tips.

Comment: I updated my original post to conform to several of your suggestions and add some more improvements of my own. =)