# Locating a bitmap inside another (larger) bitmap with F#

Tags: array, image, f#

This is my firstish (heavily rewritten) go at the completed project that I've been working on with CodeReview assistance, so further advice is appreciated! See [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57167/load-bitmap-object-data-into-array-of-byte-values), [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57343/transforming-a-byte-array-into-an-array-of-byte-arrays-with-f) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57625/transform-bitmap-object-into-jagged-array-of-rgb-tuple-values) for the past history of the project.

I strongly suspect there's a much more functional way to manage my loops, so assistance with that area especially is what I would like.

I have a separate set of unit tests ([visible here](https://github.com/Kenneth-Posey/LearningFsharp/blob/master/FsharpTutorial/YeFsharpLibrary/UnitTest.fs)) which confirm that this code works with my two sample image sets.

```
namespace MathAlgorithms

module ArrayFunctions = 
    // Generic because it makes testing easier, yay math
    let SearchSubset (tSmallArray:'a[][]) (tLargeArray:'a[][]) (pCoordinate:(int * int)) =
        let tSmallHeight = tSmallArray.Length
        let tSmallWidth = tSmallArray.[0].Length

        let tHeightIndex = fst pCoordinate
        let tWidthIndex = snd pCoordinate
        let mutable tSmallHeightIndex = 0
        let mutable tSmallWidthIndex = 0
        let mutable tMatch = true

        try 
            while ( tSmallHeightIndex < tSmallHeight - 1 ) && tMatch do
                while ( tSmallWidthIndex < tSmallWidth - 1 ) && tMatch do
                    let tLargeCurrentValue = tLargeArray.[tHeightIndex + tSmallHeightIndex].[tWidthIndex + tSmallWidthIndex]
                    let tSmallCurrentValue = tSmallArray.[tSmallHeightIndex].[tSmallWidthIndex]

                    if tSmallCurrentValue = tLargeCurrentValue then
                        tSmallWidthIndex <- tSmallWidthIndex + 1         
                    else
                        tMatch <- false

                tSmallWidthIndex  <- 0
                tSmallHeightIndex <- tSmallHeightIndex + 1

            tMatch
        with
            | _ -> false

namespace FsharpImaging

open System
open System.Drawing
open System.Drawing.Imaging
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open MathAlgorithms

module ImageFunctions = 
    let LoadBitmapIntoArray (pBitmap:Bitmap) =
        let tBitmapData = pBitmap.LockBits( Rectangle(Point.Empty, pBitmap.Size), 
                                            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, 
                                            PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb )  
        let tImageArrayLength = Math.Abs(tBitmapData.Stride) * pBitmap.Height
        let tImageDataArray = Array.zeroCreate<byte> tImageArrayLength

        Marshal.Copy(tBitmapData.Scan0, tImageDataArray, 0, tImageArrayLength)
        pBitmap.UnlockBits(tBitmapData)

        ( pBitmap.Width, pBitmap.Height, tBitmapData.Stride ), tImageDataArray

        // Notes:
        // Image pixel data is stored BGR ( blue green red )
        // Image data is padded to be divisible by 4 (int32 width)

    let Transform2D ( (pDimension:int*int*int), (pArray:byte[]) ) = 
        let tWidth, tHeight, tStride = pDimension

        [|
            for tHeightIndex in 0 .. ( tHeight - 1 ) do
                let tStart  = tHeightIndex * tStride
                let tFinish = ( tStart + tWidth * 3 ) - 1
                yield [|    
                    for tWidthIndex in tStart .. 3 .. tFinish do
                        yield ( pArray.[tWidthIndex]
                              , pArray.[tWidthIndex + 1] 
                              , pArray.[tWidthIndex + 2] )
                |]
        |]



module ImageSearch = 
    open ImageFunctions

    let SearchBitmap (pSmallBitmap:Bitmap) (pLargeBitmap:Bitmap) = 

        let tSmallArray = Transform2D <| LoadBitmapIntoArray pSmallBitmap 
        let tLargeArray = Transform2D <| LoadBitmapIntoArray pLargeBitmap

        let tSearchWidth = pLargeBitmap.Width - pSmallBitmap.Width
        let tSearchHeight = pLargeBitmap.Height - pSmallBitmap.Height

        let mutable tHeightIndex = 0
        let mutable tWidthIndex = 0
        let mutable tMatch = false
        let mutable tContinue = true

        while ( tHeightIndex < tSearchHeight - 1 ) && tContinue do
            while ( tWidthIndex < tSearchWidth - 1 ) && tContinue do
                let tCurrentValue = tLargeArray.[tHeightIndex].[tWidthIndex]
                let tFirstSmallPixel = tSmallArray.[0].[0]

                if tCurrentValue = tFirstSmallPixel then
                    tMatch <- ArrayFunctions.SearchSubset tSmallArray tLargeArray ( tHeightIndex, tWidthIndex )
                    if tMatch then tContinue <- false

                if tMatch = false && tContinue = true then
                    tWidthIndex <- tWidthIndex + 1

            if tMatch = false && tContinue = true then
                tWidthIndex  <- 0                       // Reset to search next row
                tHeightIndex <- tHeightIndex + 1

        tMatch, tWidthIndex, tHeightIndex

namespace MainProgram

open System.Drawing
open System.Drawing.Imaging
open System.Diagnostics
open FsharpImaging

module Main = 
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main (args:string[]) = 

        use tSmallBitmap = new Bitmap("searchimage.bmp")
        use tLargeBitmap = new Bitmap("containingimage.bmp")

        let tSuccess, xCoord, yCoord = ImageSearch.SearchBitmap tSmallBitmap tLargeBitmap

        // Must return from function
        0
```

Comment: Note: if somebody can show me how to change my while-do loop to be more F#-ish/functional, I will happily put a bounty on this question. =)

Comment: Updated my OP to include new, fixed code. The program is in a working state now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`try ... with | _ -> false` is bad. Like, **very bad**. The equivalent in C# is

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return false;
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7152374) on SO for good advice on exception handling, and this one line in particular:

> Only catch what you can handle and recover from.

In that particular code, the only exception I can imagine being thrown is an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, which you definitely want to know about. If it's thrown, it means your code is wrong.

---

I mentioned in a [previous answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/57632/44723) that Hungarian notation is dead and buried, and I feel that I'm not going to change your mind, but I will say it again just in case :) tImagine pIf tMy tReview pLooked tLike tThis...

---

You can use pattern matching to simplify this

> ```
> let tHeightIndex = fst pCoordinate
> let tWidthIndex = snd pCoordinate
> ```

to this

```
let heightIndex, widthIndex = coordinate
```

Or since `coordinate` is only used for these values, you can change the function signature to

```
let SearchSubset (smallArray : 'a[][]) (largeArray : 'a[][]) (heightIndex : int, widthIndex : int)
```

While we're looking at this, `SearchSubset` is a misleading name. I would suggest `isSubmatrix`.

---

I'm not sure, but it looks like you have off-by-one errors in these lines:

> ```
> while ( tSmallHeightIndex < tSmallHeight - 1 ) && tMatch do
>     while ( tSmallWidthIndex < tSmallWidth - 1 ) && tMatch do
> ```

I would think `smallHeightIndex` should range over `[0, smallHeight)`, and similarly for `smallWidthIndex`.

---

Now as for the loops... I'm going to sidestep the entire issue by suggesting another way of writing this. F# has nice support for array slices and structural equality, which allows us to write the following:

```
let isSubmatrix (small : 'a[][]) (large : 'a[][]) (y : int, x : int) : bool =
    // TODO: bounds checking.
    let yMax = y + small.Length - 1
    let xMax = x + small.[0].Length - 1
    large.[y .. yMax] |> Array.map (fun row -> row.[x .. xMax]) = small
```

And some sample tests

```
let large = [| [| 0; 1; 2 |]
             ; [| 3; 4; 5 |]
             ; [| 6; 7; 8 |]
             ; [| 9; 10; 11 |] |]

printfn "%A" <| isSubmatrix [| [| 6; 7 |] ; [| 9 ; 10 |] |] large (2, 0)
printfn "%A" <| isSubmatrix [| [| 6; 7; 8 |] ; [| 9 ; 10; 11 |] |] large (2, 0)
printfn "%A" <| isSubmatrix [| [| 1 |] ; [| 4 |] |] large (0, 1)
```

OK, so what's going on here? Let's look at what the slices are doing.

`large.[y .. yMax]` will give us \$n\$ rows of `large` starting at row `y`, where \$n\$ is the number of rows in `small`.

`Array.map (fun row -> row.[x .. xMax])` will then give us \$m\$ elements of each row, starting at column `x`, where \$m\$ is the number of columns in `small`.

For example,

```
printfn "%A" (large.[2 .. 3] |> Array.map (fun row -> row.[1 .. 2]))
```

will print

> ```
> [|[|7; 8|]; [|10; 11|]|]
> ```

F# even supports slicing 2D arrays, which is nice:

```
let isSubmatrix (small : 'a[,]) (large : 'a[,]) (y : int, x : int) : bool =
    // TODO: bounds checking.
    let yMax = y + Array2D.length1 small - 1
    let xMax = x + Array2D.length2 small - 1
    large.[y .. yMax, x .. xMax] = small
```

Comment: I'm still digesting your answer and advice. I'm sure I'll have questions later. =)

Comment: You'll be happy to know that in my refactoring my code to use recursive loops rather than while-do loops, I've been stripping out my pseudo-hungarian notation. That style makes a lot of sense to me in more object oriented design, but it's starting to add more confusion than clarity for functional programming. =)

Comment: Just a note, concerning the off by one error, I checked with and without the loop shortened by one, and I get an out-of-range-index error when I don't subtract one from my search range and domain. So I think it would indicate that the -1 is necessary. =)